# How to get my TextView clickable to display the alert diaglog box?

Tags: android-studio

I have the following code but the word "reset password" is not clickable. Even after I add some attributes to my xml, I still can't get it to be clicked. I thought that we should be using a button instead of a textview for clicking on? I have linked the variables to my xml file and set the relevant TextView for it.

```
 public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private TextView reset_password;
    private Button login;
    private Button register;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        register = findViewById(R.id.register);
        reset_password = findViewById(R.id.reset_password);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String txt_email = email.getText().toString();
                String txt_password = password.getText().toString();
                loginUser(txt_email, txt_password);
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));

            }
        });

    }

    private void loginUser(String email, String password) {

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        reset_password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


       public void onClick(View v) {


                    final EditText resetMail = new EditText(v.getContext());
                    AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                    passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Reset Password ?");
                    passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Enter Your Email To Received Reset Link");
                    passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // extract the email and send reset link
                            String mail = resetMail.getText().toString().trim();
                            auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(mail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Reset Link Sent To Your Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error! Reset Link is Not Sent" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // close the dialog
                        }
                    });

                    passwordResetDialog.create().show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

This is my xml code:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forgot Password"
        android:layout_below="@id/password"
        android:id="@+id/reset_password"/>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The textview won't click at all.... even when I added the attribute clickable=true etc

Comment: I thought that only a button is clickable?

Comment: I thought that a textview is not a button and won't click

Comment: You can click on TextView

Comment: but in this case... I can't.... I can't think of anything else to fix

Comment: I dont understand whats the problem

Comment: apologies... I got it working... I think I just place it in the wrong spot... just move it around the brackets and it works..